# WordPress: Paginating a single Page?

Tags: wordpress

I was wondering if someone knows about an option to paginate a regular page?
Couldn't find any additional info online.

The thing is I'm looking to create a page (default page template) with the possibility to paginate it.

Am I missing something or is that not possible?!

*Edit* :
Just a clarification, I'm referring to the page.php template, not any other file such as the index/archive/post etc as those are pretty straight forward.

Thanks!! :-)

Comment: Are you looking for the [Post Pagination](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_posts_pagination)?

Comment: I'm looking to achieve a similar result but only for the page.php template

Comment: @PieterGoosen you're actually right, I was a bit stupid here. It does work on a regular blank page.
However, what I really wanted to achieve, is to run a query on a custom page template, and have infinite scroll working on that page. For some reason it doesn't work for me. (The link I have does show xyz.com/page-name/page/2 but this link won't load any additional posts. When I go to this link it's getting a 404 message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most well-coded themes, all you have to do is paste this code: `<!––nextpage––>` wherever you want the next page to start.

If for some reason, pagination is not showing up after you have pasted the next page tags, then you would need to add the following code in your `single.php` loop.

```
<?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this is only valid for posts rather than Pages. I'm looking to have that on the page.php file.

Comment: You can also use plugins. I use this one
https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-content-pagination/

Comment: That's also for posts and I'm looking to implement it on a single page.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the short answer is, you guys are right.

The long answer is that due to a custom post type setting, (has_archive was set to false) the pagination didn't work on the page.php template, but did work on the front page.